# Two actions within the same form

Tags: ajax, laravel, forms, submit

I need your help. I have 5 forms on my PHP page and send the processing of the data without a submit button. I do this through sending data to my controller (store) that processes the data and returns the information I need to another page. The submission of the form is done by an AJAX function.

The problem is that now I need to get the information filled out by the user in the forms and by clicking on a button generate a PDF with the options marked by it. How could have two distinct actions within the same form? Necessary that the data be processed without submitting as it already does and after being processed you can click on a button that goes to another page.

Ajax Function:

```
function enviaForm(){            
        var url = $("#formulario").attr("action");     
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  url,
            data: $("#formulario").serialize(),           
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "visible");
            },
            success: function($retorno){               
                $("#inputLimCalculado").text ($retorno.limFinal); 
                $("#inputRisco1").text ($retorno.risco1); 
                $("#inputRisco2").text ($retorno.risco2);   
                $("#inputAuxCheqOuro").text ($retorno.auxCheqOuro); 
                $("#inputAuxCartaoEmp").text ($retorno.auxCartaoEmp); 
                preencherPortfolio();                           
            },
            error: function($retorno){
                console.log($retorno);
            }, 
            complete: function(){
                $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
        });           
        preencherPortfolio();
}
```

Form:

```
@extends('entidades.layout')
<header class="row">
        @include('entidades.header')
</header>
@section('conteudo')
<div class="container">         
    <br> 
    {{ csrf_field()}}    
 
    <table class="table table-primary"> 
        <tr>    
                <td>MCI: {{ $entidades->cd_cli}}</td>
                <td>Entidade: {{$entidades->nome}}</td>                                 
        </tr>
        <tr>        
                <td>Atividade: {{$entidades->nom_atv}}</td>     
                <td>Natureza: {{$entidades->nom_atv}}</td>      
        </tr>           
    </table>        
    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ route('entidade.index') }}'">Voltar à Consulta</button>     
</div>  

<div class="container">       
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="entidadeBtn">
                Dados da Entidade
        </button>  

        <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" type="button" id="dirigente1Btn" onclick="validaFormEnt();">
                Dirigente 1
        </button>        
       
        <button class="btn btn-primary collapsed" type="button" id="dirigente2Btn">
                Dirigente 2
        </button>   

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="portfolioBtn" onclick="validarDirigentes();">
                Portfólio
        </button>  

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="parecerBtn">
                Parecer                
        </button>  
        
        <!-- botão teste para o desenvolvedor -->
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="desenvBtn">
                Desenvolvedor
        </button>  
        <!-- enviar dados na controller store para o cálculo do modelo                         -->
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('entidade.store') }}" name="form" id="formulario">                                             
                <input type="hidden" name="mci" value="{{$mci}}"/> 
                <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>  
                <input type="hidden" name="cd_nat" value="{{$entidades->cd_nat}}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="nom_atv" value="{{$entidades->nom_atv}}"/>
                <!-- Receber se os formulários foram preenchidos -->
                <input type="hidden" name="entControle" id="entControle" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="dirig1Controle" id="dirig1Controle" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="dirig2Controle" id="dirig2Controle" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                
                <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- //////Formulário da entidade////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <div id="entidadesToggle" style="display:none;">
                        @include('entidades.entidade')                                                                          
                </div>  
        
                <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- /////////Formulário do dirigente 1//////////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               
                <div id="dirigente1Toggle" style="display:none;">                                
                        @include('entidades.dirigente1')                                                                   
                </div>

                <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- /////////Formulário do dirigente 2//////////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <div id="dirigente2Toggle" style="display:none;">
                        @include('entidades.dirigente2') 
                </div>
                

                <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- /////////////////////////////////Portfólio//////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <div id="portfolioToggle" style="display:none;">
                        @include('entidades.portfolio')                                                                          
                </div>        
                                
                <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- /////////////////////////////////Parecer/////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

                <div id="parecerToggle"  style="display:none;">           
                        @include('entidades.parecer')                           
                </div> 
                 <!-- botão para gerar súmula -->
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="gerarBtn" action="pagina.php" >
                Gerar Súmula
        </button>                                     
        </form>      
        <div class="ajax-loader" style = "display:none;">
                <img src="{{ url('img/ajax-loader.gif') }}" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Controler:

```
public function store(Request $request){
......
return json_encode(['limFinal'=> $limFinal, 'mci'=> $mci, 'risco1'=>$risco1, 'risco2'=>$risco2,
        'auxCheqOuro'=>$auxCheqOuro, 'auxCartaoEmp'=>$auxCartaoEmp]);
}
```

Comment: can you please share proper html and controller code?

Comment: I shared the form, but the controller is very large because it has the whole business rule.

Comment: you can also create actions on the basis of `button id` in js functions and hit ajax request. there are many events in jquery.